# Sign new .apk file with Specific private key

Tags: android

I want to sign my .apk file with the key which I used to sign my previous version, unfortunately I dont have the same keystore avalaible but Google Play do provide me with previous key which I used to sign the file. I am using Eclipse, is there any way around?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you don't have the original which has the public/private components, that you'll need to generate a new one.  And, you'll want to backup.

Comment: Can i download the original apk file from Google Play's developer console?

Comment: Perhaps as that's what's downloaded when people install... that won't give you your key in all components, though.